# Linearize non linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

Is it possible to linearize the function $f(x) = 1-exp(\frac{x}{b})$ so that one could use it in a linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

In linear regression usually exponential functions are logarithmized:
$$ \log(1-f(x))=x/b$$
Don't know if it helps in your case.
Google:
Linear regression, transformations.

Comment: In order the model be linear with respect to parameters, I wonder if it should not be $\log(1-f(x))=\alpha x$

Comment: Take $a=1/b$ then you have it

Comment: For sure, but in the form with $\alpha$, you can directly use the standard formula for linear regression.